# getting the id of a containing div when starting to drag with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, draggable, droppable

I have an element which is draggable and then several elements which are droppable on the same page.

When dragging starts I want to find out the id of the div containing the draggable element in its original position. I have found info on how to get the id of the element which is being dragged but not the id of the parent element from whence it came.

Here's some code:

```
<div id="row-2col0" class="droppable"><a href class="draggable"></a></div>
<div id="row-2col1" class="droppable"></div>
<div id="row-2col2" class="droppable"></div>

$('.draggable').draggable({start: function() {var initialposition = ???}});
$('.droppable').droppable({drop: handleDropEvent, accept:'.bookmark'});
function handleDropEvent( event, ui ) {

}
```

I want to get the id of the parent element so that I can use it in the handleDropEvent function. I'm hoping if I can get hold of it in the draggable start function then I can use it in the handleDropEvent function?

thanks

Comment: `$(this).parent('div').attr('id')`

Comment: Hey there - thanks for that, I'm not sure if it works or not though! in my code where I have var initialposition = ???, if I put your code in there, how can I make it available in the handleDropEvent function? Is it possible? Thanks friend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(this) in the draggable start event function is the element being dragged.
If you want the  div containing the draggable element you can use:

```
$(this).closest("div")
```

For your requirement however I'd recommend using:

```
ui.draggable.closest("div")
```

in the drop event function of the droppable.

Comment: Hi, thanks. But if I use the ui.draggable.closest("div") in the drop event of the droppable that will give me the id of the div where the draggable has been dragged to presumably? Whereas I need the id of where if came from.

Comment: No. It will tell you the containing div where the draggable has been dragged *from*.

Comment: @ZaphodBeeblebrox, you can test this in the jsfiddle:  
    http://jsfiddle.net/martyk/bJQy9/
 if you like